# Python IPC via SSH

Tags: python, ssh, ipc

I am planning to write a tool that connects several home automation systems (Raspberry Pis) via the Internet. I do not want to write my own authentication system but want to make use of SSH:

`[Device] <-python-> [Raspberry Pi] <-ssh-> [Raspberry Pi] <-python-> [Device]`

The devices on either side are supposed to be controlled by a persistent python daemon. The tricky part is I want to enable either side to connect to the opposing side and change settings or fetch data from it. How would I achieve that?

I do not want to use SSH port forwarding as both internet connections could be interrupted at any time (consumer level DSL).

Comment: SSH port forwarding, as any TCP/IP protocol, continue working even of interruptions (if not to say, traffic faults are the normal case on the Net).

Comment: Yes, but the IP of either side might change.

Comment: Then SSH port forwarding is one of the modes to circumvent problems due to NAT'ing and dynamic IP's. Anyway al least you need one fix IP or a way to resolve a name to an IP.

Comment: Have you considered using Dynamic DNS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) as part of your solution?